# Haskell - Tree Recursion - Out Of Memory

Tags: haskell, recursion, out-of-memory

The following code with any real-logic "hollowed out" still runs out of memory when compiled on GHC 7.10.3 with the -O flag. I do not understand why a simple tree recursion with at-most a stack-depth of 52 (number of cards in a standard deck) needs so much memory. I tried using `seq` on the result variables, but that did not help. Could someone take a look and let me know why the memory usage is so high, and what can I do to avoid it?

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

type Card = (Int, Char)

compute_rank_multiplicity_map :: [Card] -> M.Map Int Int
compute_rank_multiplicity_map cards = M.fromList [(x, x) | (x, _) <- cards]

determine_hand :: [Card] -> (Int, [(Int, Int)])
determine_hand [] = error "Card list is empty!"
determine_hand cards = (0, mult_rank_desc_list)
  where rank_mult_map = compute_rank_multiplicity_map cards
        mult_rank_desc_list = M.toDescList rank_mult_map

check_kicker_logic :: [Card] -> (Int, Int)
check_kicker_logic cards =
  let first_cards = take 5 cards
      second_cards = drop 5 cards
      first_hand@(f_h, f_mrdl) = determine_hand first_cards
      second_hand@(s_h, s_mrdl) = determine_hand second_cards
  in if (first_hand > second_hand) || (first_hand < second_hand) -- is there a clear winner?
     then if (f_h == s_h) && (head f_mrdl) == (head s_mrdl) -- do we need kicker logic?
          then (1, 1)
          else (0, 1)
     else (0, 0)

card_deck :: [Card]
card_deck = [(r, s) | r <- [2 .. 14], s <- ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']]

need_kicker_logic :: [Card] -> (Int, Int)
need_kicker_logic cards = visit_subset cards (length cards) [] 0 (0, 0)
  where visit_subset a_cards num_a_cards picked_cards num_picked_cards result@(num_kicker_logic, num_clear_winners)
          | num_cards_needed == 0 = (num_kicker_logic + nkl, num_clear_winners + ncw)
          | num_cards_needed > num_a_cards = result
          | otherwise = let result_1 = visit_subset (tail a_cards)
                                                    (num_a_cards - 1)
                                                    picked_cards
                                                    num_picked_cards
                                                    result
                            result_2 = visit_subset (tail a_cards)
                                                    (num_a_cards - 1)
                                                    ((head a_cards) : picked_cards)
                                                    (num_picked_cards + 1)
                                                    result_1
                        in result_2
          where num_cards_needed = 10 - num_picked_cards
                (nkl, ncw) = check_kicker_logic picked_cards


main :: IO ()
main =
  do
    putStrLn $ show $ need_kicker_logic card_deck
```

Comment: `seq` may not help because it only forces WHNF, you may want to try `deepseq`. At least for me it makes `ghci` run this function in apparently constant memory (I didn't wait for the function to finish).

Comment: I haven't really analyzed this, but you might try `otherwise = case a_cards of {hd:tl -> let result1 = ...}`. That way, you're sure to actually take the list apart as you go rather than building a bunch of thunks to do so. Also, you may find it helpful to use a custom "strict pair" type rather than `(Int, Int)`.

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html)?